# when write "\n", why two characters are replaced?

Tags: python, file, io, newline, txt

test.txt:

```
12345
```

code:

```
dfh = open("test.txt", "r+")
dfh.seek(0, 0)
dfh.write("\n")
dfh.close()
```

output:

```
(empty line)
345
```

I expected output to be

```
(empty line)
2345
```

why "\n" replace two chracters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation I think you are using windows since windows uses 2 characters `\r\n` to get to a new line.

Quoting from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760209/java-why-is-n-considered-2-characters-in-a-read-text-file-situation)